# Creating graduated legend for rasters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, legend

I have see a few posts about the difficulties of generating nice looking legends for rasters but they all seem to relate to older versions of QGIS (Las Palmas and older). I'm on 3.4.4 and want to know what is the best way to create a legend entry for a graduated raster with many values such as a DEM.

Are there any plug-ins designed for this that work with 3.4.4?

Comment: You say that you have seen "a few posts about the difficulties of generating nice looking legends for rasters but they all seem to relate to older versions of QGIS (Las Palmas and older)".  What are links to those?

Comment: If anyone wants to provide a 3.4.4 answer they should do so at the duplicate. For why I suggest this see https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4420/115

Comment: Thanks for responding -  I am not super familiar with the etiquette here and didn't know that commenting on an old thread to ask about 3.4.4 was more acceptable than making a slightly overlapping post.

Comment: I've added a bounty of 100 to the duplicate to hopefully stimulate a refresh of the answers there.